# c# Connection must be valid and open to commit transaction TransactionScope

Tags: c#

I'm using Transactions on my Dao and in particular I'm using the TransactionScope object for the first time. But when I compile and start my procedure on my pc the method I wrote in will give me this error:

**Connection must be valid and open to commit transaction**

code:

```
    public String insert(NewsVo news)
{
    string query = "";
    MySqlCommand cmd = null;


    try
    {

        using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
        {
            using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection("Server=localhost;Uid=root;Pwd=root;Database=Sql300365_1"))
            {
                conn.Open();
                Int32 numTotali = Int32.Parse(getCount());
                for (int i = numTotali - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                {
                    query = "UPDATE " + table + " SET " + table + ".Priorita  = ?PrioritaSet WHERE Priorita = ?Priorita";
                    cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, conn);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("?Priorita", MySqlDbType.Int64).Value = i;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("?PrioritaSet", MySqlDbType.Int64).Value = i + 1;
                    cmd.ExecuteReader();
                }


                query = "INSERT INTO " + table + " (Priorita,  Data, Titolo) VALUES (0, ?Data, ?Titolo)";

                cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, conn);
                //cmd.Transaction = Transazione;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("?Data", MySqlDbType.VarChar, ConstDao.LENGHT_NEWS_DATA).Value = news.Data;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("?Titolo", MySqlDbType.VarChar, ConstDao.LENGHT_NEWS_TITOLO).Value = news.Titolo;
                cmd.ExecuteReader();
                news.IdNumber = cmd.LastInsertedId.ToString();


                scope.Complete();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception(ex.Message.ToString());
    }
    finally
    {
        cmd.Dispose();
    }
    return news.IdNumber;
}
```

Comment: Please post the question in *English*

Comment: Pretty sure you want `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` instead of `cmd.ExecuteReader()`  ... but I have no idea what you're asking so it's a shot in the dark.

Comment: You're not disposing your reader... `using (cmd.ExecuteReader()){}` or `var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(); reader.Close(); reader.Dispose();`

Answer (score 1):

You need to move `scope.Complete();` within your connection `using` as it is being disposed before you are completing your scope.  Also, change your calls to use `ExecuteNonQuery` as opposed to `ExecuteReader`, as you are opening a `SqlDataReader` and not disposing of it.

```
using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection("Server=localhost;Uid=root;Pwd=root;Database=Sql300365_1"))
{
        conn.Open();
        Int32 numTotali = Int32.Parse(getCount());
        for (int i = numTotali - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
             query = "UPDATE " + table + " SET " + table + ".Priorita  = ?PrioritaSet WHERE Priorita = ?Priorita";
             cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, conn);
             cmd.Parameters.Add("?Priorita", MySqlDbType.Int64).Value = i;
             cmd.Parameters.Add("?PrioritaSet", MySqlDbType.Int64).Value = i + 1;
             cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

   query = "INSERT INTO " + table + " (Priorita,  Data, Titolo) VALUES (0, ?Data, ?Titolo)";
   cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, conn);
   cmd.Parameters.Add("?Data", MySqlDbType.VarChar, ConstDao.LENGHT_NEWS_DATA).Value = news.Data;
   cmd.Parameters.Add("?Titolo", MySqlDbType.VarChar, ConstDao.LENGHT_NEWS_TITOLO).Value = news.Titolo;
   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
   news.IdNumber = cmd.LastInsertedId.ToString();                    

   scope.Complete();
}
```

Comment: @J.Steen - Sorry, that was in reference to his answer to his own question, where he moved it outside of the using.

Answer (score 0):

ok Ok i have inverted using connection with scope
And I opened the connection before scope and works !
I hope it is right, thank you !

```
 public String insert(NewsVo news)
{
    string query = "";
    MySqlCommand cmd = null;
    try
    {           


            using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection("Server=localhost;Uid=root;Pwd=root;Database=Sql300365_1"))
            {
                using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
                {
                conn.Open();
                Int32 numTotali = Int32.Parse(getCount());
                for (int i = numTotali - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                {
                    query = "UPDATE " + table + " SET " + table + ".Priorita  = ?PrioritaSet WHERE Priorita = ?Priorita";
                    cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, conn);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("?Priorita", MySqlDbType.Int64).Value = i;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("?PrioritaSet", MySqlDbType.Int64).Value = i + 1;
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }

                query = "INSERT INTO " + table + " (Priorita,  Data, Titolo) VALUES (0, ?Data, ?Titolo)";
                cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, conn);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("?Data", MySqlDbType.VarChar, ConstDao.LENGHT_NEWS_DATA).Value = news.Data;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("?Titolo", MySqlDbType.VarChar, ConstDao.LENGHT_NEWS_TITOLO).Value = news.Titolo;
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                news.IdNumber = cmd.LastInsertedId.ToString();
                scope.Complete();
            }

       }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception(ex.Message.ToString());
    }
    finally
    {
        cmd.Dispose();
    }
    return news.IdNumber;
}
```